# How to set time in Docker container at build time

Tags: docker, date, dockerfile, alpine-linux

So I'm trying to build an Alpine container, including an app that requires `bash` and `curl` to install.

Trouble is that Alpine seems to think the year is 2037 (possibly because of the host Pi's lack of a hardwareClock) ignoring the correct host OS/system time (kept up-to-date by NTP), so the apk call fails:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  bash (no such package):
    required by: world[bash]
  curl (no such package):
    required by: world[curl]
```

One can use `docker run -it --privileged ...` to launch the container in interactive mode, and the time will be set correctly, so the installation goes off without a hitch.
A reference I found suggests that `privileged` builds are not possible (ref?).

I've tried many ways to pass the time into the container at build time, all unsuccessfully:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine:3.14
# Pass build-time using `--build-arg time=$(date +%s)` (w/ default value)
ARG time=1632511895
#RUN ["/bin/date", "-s", "@$time"]      # `invalid date @$time`
#RUN ["/bin/date", "-s", "@"$time]      # `/bin/date/` not found
#RUN echo $(date)       # no output
#RUN date -s @$time     # `date: can't set date: Operation not permitted`
#RUN sudo date -s @$time        # /bin/sh: sudo: not found

# cannot build with `--privileged` so clock will be in 2037 and apk will fail
RUN apk add --no-cache curl bash
WORKDIR /tmp
```

How can I install `curl` and `bash` at build-time??

## Attempts

- Tried setting the timezone as specified [here](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136): no effect
- Tried forcing apk to use HTTP with `RUN sed -i 's/https/http/g' /etc/apk/repositories` before the `apk` command (TY @jan-garaj): I only got a new/additional error: `The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache curl bash' returned a non-zero code: 2`

## More info

```
# date       
Sat Oct 23 13:17:47 EDT 2021

# docker info
    Client:
     Debug Mode: false
    
    Server:
     Containers: 4
      Running: 0
      Paused: 0
      Stopped: 4
     Images: 19
     Server Version: 19.03.15
     Storage Driver: overlay2
      Backing Filesystem: extfs
      Supports d_type: true
      Native Overlay Diff: true
     Logging Driver: json-file
     Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
     Plugins:
      Volume: local
      Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
      Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
     Swarm: inactive
     Runtimes: runc
     Default Runtime: runc
     Init Binary: docker-init
     containerd version: 269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
     runc version: ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
     init version: fec3683
     Security Options:
      seccomp
       Profile: default
     Kernel Version: 4.19.66-v7+
     Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
     OSType: linux
     Architecture: armv7l
     CPUs: 4
     Total Memory: 858.7MiB
     Name: rpi0.crcondo
     ID: WW63:IXLY:OBPE:AX4O:45H7:OAUH:CELE:ALDG:ZHC3:RTQW:I32M:GSDL
     Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
     Debug Mode: false
     Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
     Labels:
     Experimental: false
     Insecure Registries:
      127.0.0.0/8
     Live Restore Enabled: false
    
    WARNING: No swap limit support
    WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
    WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Comment: That post refers to setting the timezone - I'm not off by hours, but by years. Also, I'm using Alpine, not Ubuntu. It did link [here](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136) but this was also specific to timezones. (I tried it anyways: no effect)

Comment: Alpine has some oddities with how it inherits time from the host system. In the past, I've worked around this by setting the SYS_TIME capability when running the container. While this capability should only be required to set the host's time from within the docker container, it does seem to force a clock sync to the container. Admittedly, I cannot reproduce your issue, so I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, but it's an easy fix to test.

Comment: I found referenced to using `--cap-add` with `docker run`; except this is a build issues, and I can't find any docs that specify how to leverage `--cap-add` with `docker build`.

Comment: Sure enough. I dug out an old rasp pi and reformatted, and I can reproduce your issue now, so at least it's not something weird with your environment. I have not been able to figure out a fix though, whether using vanilla docker build or kaniko (which builds a container inside a container allowing the use or --privileged to set the time), I get the issue in both cases.

Comment: Of course it’s set in the Pi (otherwise HTTPS and lots of other stuff breaks); the issue is docker build isn’t passing the correct time into the build image

Comment: My only other theory would be to use a hwclock-emulation tool to make this accessible [in the spot Docker looks for it] when running the build-process... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @JanGaraj's answer gave me an important lead: [Alpine 3.14's release notes](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0) mention that it requires `Docker >=20.10.0` (I am currently on `19.03.15`).

Going back to [Alpine 3.13's release notes](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.13.0):

- The Docker version requirement is `19.03.9` [which I have]
- *along with* `libseccomp 2.4.2`

Simply using `FROM alpine:3.13` still didn't work.

Checking the second requirement, I had a previous version of `libseccomp[2]` and web-searching led me to this post: https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/

Using the steps therein to upgrade `libseccomp[2]` did the trick for *both* `alpine:3.13` and `alpine:3.14`!!

## The steps to fix (from the post)

> The steps for libseccomp2 are well documented, as this has been a problem on multiple platforms (not just RPI4). You could do a 'oneshot' installation of a newer version, which can be found here https://github.com/itzg/docker-minecraft-server/issues/755#issuecomment-781615497
>
> Personally I feel the better method is to install it from the Buster Backports repo, which is very safe to add. It also means any future updates to libseccomp will be applied to the Pi.

```
# Get signing keys to verify the new packages, otherwise they will not install
rpi ~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138

# Add the Buster backport repository to apt sources.list
rpi ~$ echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list

rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libseccomp2 -t buster-backports
```

Now on to the next build-time error message

Answer (score 0):

I would answer "How can I install curl and bash at build-time" not "How to set time in Docker container at build time":

I guess apk is failing because repo TLS certificate `dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org` is not valid after 2037 = valid TLS connection can be created. You only need to install package, so you may sacrifice TLS security in this case and plain HTTP connectuon to repository can be used as a workaround. E.g.

```
RUN \
  sed -i 's/https/http/g' /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --no-cache curl bash
```

Unfortunately, [apk doesn't have any flag to ignore TLS verification](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/-/issues/10650), so only this workaround can be used for now.

BTW: I would try to use good old NTP on host Pi. Containers use host time, so proper time configuration (via NTP sync) on the host level should resolve also problem on the container level (and then also problem with TLS cert verification).

---

Update:

See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0:

So you need to upgrade your Docker version (`20.10.0+`), you have only `19.03.15`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this! Unfortunately the exact same error as above persists; the only difference is a new error: `The command '/bin/sh -c sed -i 's/https/http/g' /etc/apk/repositories &&   apk add --no-cache curl bash' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: @AdamSmooch that was only example, because I don't have your setup. It looks like you have very weird docker setup. Please provide `docker info` output. Run commands manually in the container not in the build - it is not clear which command is failing.

Comment: The error comes from the apk command (following the `sed`): `The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache curl bash' returned a non-zero code: 2`. As mentioned - running the apk commands in a container (with --privileged) works fine, since the time is correctly set. `docker info` added to the question.

Comment: @AdamSmooch see update and Alpine release notes

Comment: Tried [`alpine:3.13`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.13.0) since it requires Docker 19.03.09+, but same error... I'll try the docker upgrade next...

Comment: Actually, the 3.14 release notes led me to `libseccomp` which led to a post of another Docker + Pi user who shared a solution for the same issue (albeit on 3.13). I'll write up the full solution, but likely still award you the bounty for putting me on the right track! ‍♂️